# My HTML/PHP-form wont send emails

Tags: forms, email, send

http://pastebin.com/XKjkxmhJ

does anyone know why this wont send any emails?
it confirms it and i get the "successfully sent" message but i do not get any mail to my inbox.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Add the relevant code here it would be easier to have a look..

Comment: the whole form is in the pastebin link, i for some reason couldnt add it to the question properly

Comment: I guess you posted too much code and too little text for your question. ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that could be wrong here:

1. Try Spam folder first. Sorry if you have already done so.
2. Next, look into your sendmail setup in your server's php.ini file.
3. I hope this is not some wamp/xampp setup?
4. If any case check if server ports are open?
5. Try using external SMTP in php.ini to send mail and test that?
6. Do go through this link for more info on email setup using PHP - http://www.sitepoint.com/advanced-email-php/1/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Check your mail log (`/var/log/mail` on most machines) to see if the email was really sent, `mail()` returns true if your local MTA accepted the message, if it actually gets delivered has nothing to do with PHP after that.